# Is there any JPA annotation for SHA2 as like in mysql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework, ebean

Is there any jpa  annotation for mysql SHA2. I need to create a field in ebean which should use SHA2 through annotation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "as like in mysql"

I pressume you are referring to some **MySQL** native function/proc that helps with hashing/encrypting/decrypting operations.

Take a look [at this example tutorial](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/map-encrypted-database-columns-hibernates-columntransformer-annotation/) that is explaining how you can use [@ColumnTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ColumnTransformer.html) to invoke native DB operation such as the one you want to do.