# Translate from handmade SQL queries to framework queries (JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I had a project where I was storing salted hashed passwords like this:

```
byte[] salt = getSalt();
sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_mail, user_handle, user_password, user_salt) VALUES (?,?, SHA2(CONCAT(?, ?), 256), ?)";

prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

prepStmt.setString(1, user.getUserMail());
prepStmt.setString(2, user.getUserHandle());
//Process password
prepStmt.setString(3, user.getUserPassword());
prepStmt.setBytes(4, salt);
prepStmt.setBytes(5, salt);

prepStmt.executeUpdate();
```

The login process being:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE user_mail=? && user_password= SHA2(CONCAT(?, ?), 256)";

prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

prepStmt.setString(1, user.getUserMail());
prepStmt.setString(2, user.getUserPassword());
prepStmt.setBytes(3, salt); // being retrieved beforehand
res = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

And the update being:

```
sql = "UPDATE user_login SET user_password = SHA2(CONCAT(?, ?), 256), user_salt = ? WHERE user_id=?";

prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

// Process password
prepStmt.setString(1, newPassword);
prepStmt.setBytes(2, newSalt); // being generated beforehand
prepStmt.setBytes(3, newSalt);  

prepStmt.setInt(4, currentUser.getUserId());
```

**The important part being this** where the database does the work of salting and hashing.

```
SHA2(CONCAT(?, ?), 256)
```

Questions:

- How would I translate this part into JPA/Hibernate?
- Is it possible using "*@Query*", "*@Formula*" or something else for example?
- Is it even possible to translate to begin with? And if not, is there a way to implement such a
  thing without conflicts from JPA/Hibernate?
- Should I use database triggers/procedures?*

Thank you for your time.

**edit*

Comment: Note that SHA-2 is _not suitable for passwords_.

Comment: That's great to hear, I'll fix that part later, but what about the meat of the question ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936805/is-there-any-jpa-annotation-for-sha2-as-like-in-mysql

Comment: Refer this https://thorben-janssen.com/how-to-use-jpa-type-converter-to/